# Apache-camel Xpathbuilder performance

Tags: parsing, xpath, apache-camel, saxon

I have following question. I set up an camel -project to parse certain xml files. I have to selecting take out certain nodes from a file.

I have two files 246kb and 347kb in size. I am extracting a parent-child pair of 250 nodes in the above given example.

With the default factory here are the times. For the 246kb file respt 77secs and 106 secs. I wanted to improve the performance so switched to saxon and the times are as follows 47secs and 54secs. I was able to cut the time down by at least half.

Is it possible to cut the time further, any other factory or optimizations I can use will be appreciated.

I am using XpathBuilder to cut the xpaths out. here is an example. Is it possible to not to have to create XpathBuilder repeatedly, it seems like it has to be constructed for every xpath, I would have one instance and keep pumping the xpaths into it, maybe it will improve performance further.

```
 return XPathBuilder.xpath(nodeXpath)
            .saxon()
            .namespace(Consts.XPATH_PREFIX, nameSpace)
            .evaluate(exchange.getContext(), exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class), String.class);
```

Adding more details based on Michael's comments. So I am kind of joining them, will become clear with my example below. I am combining them into a json. 
So here we go, Lets say we have following mappings for first and second path.

pData.tinf.rexd: bm:Document/bm:xxxxx/bm:PmtInf[{0}]/bm:ReqdExctnDt/text()
pData.tinf.pIdentifi.instId://bm:Document/bm:xxxxx/bm:PmtInf[{0}]/bm:CdtTrfTxInf[{1}]/bm:PmtId/bm:InstrId/text()

This would result in a json as below

```
pData:{
  tinf: {
   rexd: <value_from_xml>
}
 pIdentifi:{

    instId: <value_from_xml>
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was able to bring the time down to 10 secs. I am using apache-camel. So I added threads there so that multiple files can be read in separate threads. Once the file was being read, it had serial operation to based on the length of the nodes that had to be traversed. I realized that it was not necessary to be serial here so introduced parrallelStream and that now gave it enough power. One thing to guard agains is not to have a proliferation of threads since that can degrade the performance. So I try to restrict the number of threads to twice or thrice the number of cores on the operating machine.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing your actual XPath expression, but given the file sizes and execution time my guess would be that you're doing a join which is being executed naively as a cartesian product, i.e. with O(n*m) performance. There is probably some way of reorganizing it to have logarithmic performance, but the devil is in the detail. Saxon-EE is quite good at optimizing join queries automatically; if not, there are often ways of doing it manually -- though XSLT gives you more options (e.g. using `xsl:key` or `xsl:merge`) than XPath does.

Comment: here are two xml paths I am using, first one gets value from the parent and the second one from the child. Lets say we have two parents. First parent has 250 children and the the other parent 50. I would then have 300 separate xml tags prepared. Parent `//bm:Document/bm:xxxxx/bm:PmtInf[{0}]/bm:ReqdExctnDt/text()``//bm:Document/bm:xxxxx/bm:PmtInf[{0}]/bm:CdtTrfTxInf[{1}]/bm:PmtId/bm:InstrId/text()`

Comment: So you're doing two separate XPath queries to retrieve two node-sets, and then comparing/joining them in the calling application? The paths are straightforward - it's what you do with the results that matters.